# php event insert/form not entering into database

Tags: php, html, insert

I am using a self-posting form with an insert, and an include page for connecting to database. When i run the process on the website, all if/else statements show true(meaning the site confirms the entry). But when I check my phpMyAdmin database, nothing has been stored. I am confused because the website confirms everything as entered, but my database wont populate. Lines and chunks have been commented out for the sake of experimentation. here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset ($_SESSION['uname']) == "true")    //If this is a valid user allow access to this page
{
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        //The form has been submitted and needs to be processed

        include 'connectionAgain.php';  //connects to the database

        //Validate the form data here!

        //Get the name value pairs from the $_POST variable into PHP variables
        //uses the same name/value pairs from the form
        /*$event_id = $_POST[event_id];
        $event_name = $_POST[event_name];
        $event_description = $_POST[event_description];
        $event_presenter = $_POST[event_presenter];
        $event_date = $_POST[event_date];
        $event_time = $_POST[event_time];*/

        $sqlHardCode = "INSERT INTO nephilim42_341 . wdv341 (event_id, event_name, event_description, event_presenter, event_date, event_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        //Create the SQL command string
        /*$sql = "INSERT INTO wdv341 (";
        $sql .= "event_id, ";
        $sql .= "event_name, ";
        $sql .= "event_description, ";
        $sql .= "event_presenter, ";
        $sql .= "event_date, ";
        $sql .= "event_time";   //Last column does NOT have a comma after it.
        $sql .= ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";*/ //? Are placeholders for variables

        //Display the SQL command to see if it correctly formatted.
        echo "<p>$sql</p>";

        $query = $connection->prepare($sql);    //Prepares the query statement

        //Binds the parameters to the query.
        //s = string: i = integer: b = blob: d = double: (DATATYPES)
        $query->bind_param("ssssss",null, $event_name, $event_description, $event_presenter, $event_date, $event_time);

        //Run the SQL prepared statements
        if ( $query->execute() )
        {
            $sqlHardCode = "INSERT INTO nephilim42_341 . wdv341 (null, event_name, event_description, event_presenter, event_date, event_time) VALUES ( $event_name, $event_description, $event_presenter, $event_date, $event_time);";
            /*$sql = "INSERT INTO wdv341 (";
            $sql .= "event_id, ";
            $sql .= "event_name, ";
            $sql .= "event_description, ";
            $sql .= "event_presenter, ";
            $sql .= "event_date, ";
            $sql .= "event_time";   //Last column does NOT have a comma after it.
            $sql .= ") VALUES ($event_id,$event_name,$event_description,$event_presenter,$event_date,$event_time)";*/

            $message = "<h1>Your record has been successfully added to the database.</h1>";
            $message .= "<p>Please <a href='redirect.php'>view</a> your records.</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "<h1>You have encountered a problem.</h1>";
            $message .= "<h2 style='color:red'>" . mysqli_error($link) . "</h2>";   //remove this for production purposes
        }

        $query->close();
        $connection->close();   //closes the connection to the database once this page is complete.
    }// ends if submit
    else
    {
        header('location: redirect.php');
        //Form has not been seen by the user.  display the form
    }
}//end Valid User True
else
{
    //Invalid User attempting to access this page. Send person to Login Page
    //header('Location: loginPage.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WDV341 Into PHP  - Event Form</title>
<style>
    html {
        color: white;
    }

    body {
        background-color: black;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    //If the form was submitted display the INSERT result message
?>
    <h1><?php echo $message = 'Your record has been successfully entered into the database'; ?></h1>
    <h1><?php echo "Return to <a href='eventInsertForm.php'>Event Form</a>to enter more events";?></h1>

<?php
}//end if
else
{
    //Display the Form.  The user will add a new record\
    include 'redirect.php';
?>

<p>This is the input form that allows the user/customer to enter the information for an event. Once the form is submitted and validated it will call the addPresenters.php page. That page will pull the form data into the PHP and add a new record to the database.</p>
<form id="eventForm" name="eventForm" method="post" action="eventInsertForm.php">
  <p>Add a new Event</p>
  <p>Event Name:
    <input type="text" name="event_name" id="event_name" />
  </p>
    <p>Event Description:
    <textarea name="event_description" id="event_description" col = "45" rows = "5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>Event Presenter:
    <input type="text" name="event_presenter" id="event_presenter" />
  </p>
  <p>Event Date:
    <input type="text" name="event_date" id="event_date" />
  </p>
  <p>Event Time:
    <input type="text" name="event_time" id="event_time" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add Event" />
    <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Clear Form" />
  </p>
</form>
<?php
}//end else
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and the include...

```
<?php
//  This file contains the PHP coding to connect to the database.  This file uses the mysqli or improved mysql commands.
//
//  Include this file in any page that needs to access the database.  Use the PHP include command before doing any database accesses
//

$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "";
$database = "";//the name of the database.  Usually the same as the username.
$password = "";

//Builds the connection object called $db and selects the desired database.
//You will need to use the $link variable in the mysqli_query() commands whenever you run a query against the database.
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database); //$link is the connection object created by this command.

//$link is a doorway to hell!!!

//Check to make sure you properly connected to the database.  This is some sample logic more suitable to a production environment
if($link->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection Failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}
else
{
    echo "Connected Successfully";
}

//Alternative method of checking for a successful connection. 

$link = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
?>
```

Comment: maybe quotes around the $_POST vars, like `$_POST['event_name']`

Comment: Also, if you don't have the database info in the second include, you would need that too.

Comment: Do you get any database errors? If you echo out the queries you are trying to execute and insert them into the database "manually" the query passes ok?

Comment: @Resolute Press - When i use the connection file with the database login info, the webpage displays    Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\WDV341\eventInsertForm.php on line 2. Im assuming because a connection is already established.

Comment: @Viliam Abosi -. When I copy/paste the insert in the phpmyadmin database i get this error:    Error
SQL query:INSERT INTO 'nephilim42_341' . 'wdv341' (null, 'event_name', 'event_description', 'event_presenter', 'event_date', 'event_time') VALUES ( $event_name, $event_description, $event_presenter, $event_date, $event_time)
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nephilim42_341' . 'wdv341' (null, 'event_name', 'event_description', 'event_pre' at line 1

Comment: @RobinJennings seems to be an "escaping" syntax problem. Single quotes are somehow used `'` to escape the database and table name. Backticks ` should be used instead. However after quick scan I don't see where are the quotes added. Could that be some "default" setting of the `$connection->prepare`?